# Model and Db-Table Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I wanted to know is more correct to create a directly db-adapter or create a model that interfaces with db-adapter.

Make the classic operations crud with db-adapter, or you can create a model that passes then all of db-adapter:

scheme:

Controller -> Model -> Db-Adapter

or

Controller -> Db-Adapter

```
Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook class extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
     / ** Table name * /
     protected $ _name = 'table';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of your model (for example a data mapper) uses the db adapter to store & retrieve stuff from the db. The controller only passes a request to the model. The model calculates stuff with the db adapter and passes it back to the controller. so that the controller can pass it to your view...

**So first:**

User Request -> Controller - > Big Model -> Small part of Model -> DB Adapter

**After that (but not every DB Request makes it to the user):**

DB Adapter responds -> Small part of Model -> Big Model -> Controller -> View -> User's screen = Response